# generating distanced matrix for an n-dimensional hypercube

Tags: c, matlab, multidimensional-array

is there any algorithm or method of generating the adjacency matrix for a hypercube for any dimension? say your input is 5 it would create a 5-dimensional hypercube

all i can find are sources from
[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube)

and
[wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypercube.html)

Comment: What does "generating a 5-dimensional hypercube" mean?  What data needs to be generated?

Comment: well i have to setup the n-dimensional hypercube to then take the adjacency matrix of it(which isn't hard once i have it setup) to then do some eigen value and linear algebra analysis of the adjacency matrix

Comment: Ok.  Then you should definitely edit your question to say that it's the adjacency matrix that you're after.  Also, C and Matlab are very different languages; which one are you interested in?

Comment: you beat me to the edits xD thanks and yeah ican work with c or matlab fairly eaisly so that's why i put those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is a bit late, but the solution is distinct from the others and based on recursion, so hopefully someone will find it useful.

First lets build some intuition about how to build an N-cube from an (N-1) cube!
When you think of a 1-cube, it's just a line segment. To get a 2-cube(square), we make a copy of the line segment, translate it, and add edges along the path of translation.
Similarly, to get a 3-cube, we take that square, make a copy of it, translate it, and add the translation edges.
If you have a hard time visualizing that, contemplate the image below:
[image: Building cubes from one dimensional lower cubes.]

If only there was mathematical machinery that does this!
We're in luck because there is: the Kronecker product.
In essence it gives us a way to copy adjacency matrices, and then it's just a matter of glueing the results together.
Glueing is accomplished by adding the dashed lines in the above figures as additional edges in the adjacency matrix of the two copies of the lower dimensional cubes.
In picture form (because this heathen site doesn't support LaTeX):
[image: How to make the necessary copies using Kronecker products]
And that's that! The adjacency matrix for a hypercube of arbitrary dimension is the sum of these two pieces.
One last caveat: these matrices grow exponentially and are mostly filled with zeros (each node only connects to N of the 2^N other nodes), so sparse matrices are a must. Here's a quick MATLAB implementation. Enjoy!

```
function A = hypercube(N)
  if N==1
    A = sparse([0 1;1 0]);
  else
    A = kron(sparse(eye(2)),hypercube(N-1)) + ...
         kron(hypercube(1),diag(sparse(ones(1,2^(N-1)))));
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you make those visualizations as well? Really cool!

Comment: I did. As a visual learner myself, I think that multiple modalities should always be employed when trying to convey concepts. I'm glad you like them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate the vertices of a N-D unit hypercube, you can basically make an N-value truthtable. Here's some code I use for that:

```
function output = ttable(values)

  output = feval(@(y)feval(@(x)mod(ceil(repmat((1:x(1))', 1, numel(x) - 1) ./ repmat(x(2:end), x(1), 1)) - 1, repmat(fliplr(y), x(1), 1)) + 1, fliplr([1 cumprod(y)])), fliplr(values));
end
```

and to get the vertices of a 5-D hypercube you can call it like this:

```
vertices = ttable(ones(1, 5) * 2) - 1;
```

From here you can calculate the adjacency matrix by finding all vertices that differ by only one bit, i.e.:

```
adj_list = zeros(2^5, 5);
adj_mat = zeros(2^5, 2^5);
for v=1:2^5
  L1_dists = sum(abs(vertices - repmat(vertices(v, :), 2^5, 1)), 2);
  adj_list(v, :) = find(L1_dists == 1);
  adj_mat(v, find(L1_dists == 1)) = 1;
end
```

---

**Edit by someone else:**

The unintelligible code above that produces `vertices` can be simplified to this:

```matlab
d = 5;  % number of dimensions of the hypercube
y = ones(1, d) * 2;
x = fliplr([1 cumprod(y)]);
n = x(1);
x = x(2:end);
vertices = ceil(repmat((1:n).', 1, d) ./ repmat(x, n, 1));
vertices = mod(vertices - 1, 2);
```

The calls to `repeat` are no longer necessary since MATLAB R2016b, and can be left out:

```matlab
vertices = ceil((1:n).' ./ x);
vertices = mod(vertices - 1, 2);
```

It is now much easier to reason about what the code does...

Comment: this is very nice and thank you for even going a step further

Comment: i'm getting all 0's as a result? i'm going to try to figure out why

Comment: L1_dists = sum(vertices - repmat(vertices(v, :), 2^5, 1), 2); 
 this line is given me an error

Comment: is the above line supposed to be
`L1_dists = sum(adj_mat- repmat(vertices(v, :), 2^5, 1), 2);`?

Comment: Yikes! Really sorry, I messed up `adj_mat(v, L1_dists == 1) = 1`. That should have had a `find` in it. I've fixed it now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the rest is correct - it works for me. Did you copy the `ttable` function and run `vertices = ttable(ones(1, 5)*2)-1`?

Comment: what about this line ? I get this error  Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree

`L1_dists = sum(vertices - repmat(vertices(v, :), 2^5, 1), 2);`

Comment: yeah i copied it exact let me try and copy it again

Comment: check what `size(vertices)` and `size(repmat(vertices(v, :), 2^5, 1))` are. They should both be 32-by-5.

Comment: size(verticies) is 32-by-5 but size(repmat(vertices(v, :), 2^5, 1)) is giving me 1024-by-5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9875/discussion-between-richante-and-pycthon)

Comment: This is really terrible MATLAB coding, sorry to say. Why would you create an anonymous function and then immediately `feval` it? Why not just do the computation directly? That one line of code it totally unintelligible, but can be simplified and spread out over a few statements so that it's clear what it does.