# Generate all unordered pairs of bit strings with Hamming distance at most 2

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics, hamming-distance

I'm looking for an efficient way to generate all unordered pairs of bit strings (represented as integers) that have Hamming distance at most 2. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913099/3475799), it is shown how this is quite efficiently done for pairs having Hamming distance 1.

In other words, the answer above gives us all edges of the [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph). Phrased in these terms, I'm looking for an efficient way to generate the edges of the [square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power) of a hypercube.

Is there some nice known fast method, perhaps similarly based on bit tricks?

Comment: Have you considered adapting the Sieve of Eratosthenes? What have you tried at all?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I did it recursively: for each neighbor (i.e. a vertex that differs by one bit), I generated all neighbors that differ by one bit from that guy (plus a little bit of bookkeeping). I wasn't too satisfied with the performance though. To answer your first question, no, I the sieve didn't even cross my mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easy modification to [Nate Kohl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913778/2144669).

```
int n = 3;
// examine all vertices from 0...2^n-1
unsigned long long max = 1ULL << n;  
for (unsigned long long vertex = 0; vertex < max; ++vertex) {
  std::cout << vertex << ':';
  // print all vertices that differ from vertex by one bit
  unsigned long long mask = 1;
  for (int shift_amt = 0; shift_amt < n; ++shift_amt) {
    std::cout << ' ' << (vertex ^ (mask << shift_amt));
  }
  for (int shift_amt1 = 0; shift_amt1 < n; ++shift_amt1) {
    for (int shift_amt2 = 0; shift_amt2 < shift_amt1; ++shift_amt2) {
      std::cout << ' ' << (vertex ^ (mask << shift_amt1) ^ (mask << shift_amt2));
    }
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```